# Measure Theory about measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

is there a set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that, $E$ satisfy that for all set $B$, $$m^*(E)+m^*(B \cap E^c)=m^*(E \cup B)$$ (this is very close to the definition of $E$ being measurable in my book, m* here refers to outer measure), yet $E$ failed to be measurable?

my edit: I want to point out that the condition of E in this question is a necessary condition if E is measurable yet might not be sufficient as this question suggested.

second edit: as requested, the definition in my book of a set being measurable is that if $E$ is a measurable set , then for all set $A$,
$$m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A \cap E^c)=m^*(A)$$

I was able to find out that if a set is measurable, then it suffices to make my original identity. proof: let $A$ be $E \cup B$, then you will have $A \cap E$ becomes $E$, and etc to make the two equations equivalent.

Comment: For one thing, if $m^*(E)=\infty$ that identity is always true (but of course $E$ may not be measurable).

Comment: I agree thanks for the edit btw

Comment: $m^*$ is the outer measure?

Comment: Maybe add the definition from your book for comparison.

Comment: yeah its the outer measure

Comment: so nobody haven't answered, is it because it's too easy so nobody wanted to waste their time on?

Answer (score 2):

As @Gae noted in a comment, $E$ can be a nonmeasurable set with $m^*(E)=\infty$.

On the other hand, if $m^*(E)\lt\infty$, and if your identity
$$m^*(E)+m^*(B\cap E^c)=m^*(E\cup B)\tag1$$
holds for every set $B\subseteq\mathbb R$, then $E$ must be measurable.

**Proof.** There is a measurable set $D$ (in fact a $G_\delta$ set) such that $E\subseteq D$ and $m(D)=m^*(D)=m^*(E)$.
Let $B=D\cap E^c$; then $B\cap E^c=B$ and $E\cup B=D$, so your identity $(1)$ becomes
$$m^*(E)+m^*(B)=m^*(D)=m^*(E).$$
Since $m^*(E)\lt\infty$, it follows that $m^*(B)=0$, whence $B$ is measurable, and so is $D\cap B^c=E$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This make a lot sense to me now!